# Conditional operator always replaceable by if/else?

Tags: c++, conditional-operator

Until now I was thinking the conditional operator `int a = b == 2 ? x1 : x2;` is always replaceable by an if/else statement.

```
int a;
if (b == 2)
  a = x1;
else
  a = x2;
```

And the choice between one of the two is always a matter of taste. Today I was working with a task where a reference would be useful if I could write:

```
int& a;
if (b == 2)
  a = x1;
else
  a = x2;
```

This is not allowed and I tried the initialization of the reference with the conditional operator. This was working and I came to realize, that the conditional operator is not always replaceable by an if/else statement.

Am I right with this conclusion?

Comment: I removed the [c] tag as your question uses references in the corner case example

Comment: You mean `a = x1` and `a = x2`, right?

Comment: @SiegeX: Thanks, i'm not very familar with c and thougt it would also concern c as well.

Comment: Your inclusion of the assignment as part of the ternary a?b:c operator is... kind of a red herring. There are many situations where if/else and the ternary aren't interchangable. The if/else version is a statement, the ternary operator is an expression, so, for example, you can't use the if/else version as a parameter to a function call.

Comment: @Jefromi: Yes, i'm going red in the face.

Comment: Just FYI: Java allows the 2nd form (replace `int&` with `final int`); so it's just a matter of language specifications. Personally I dislike just about every language that hasn't left the C-language-syntax roots already.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are correct. The conditional operator is an *expression*, whereas `if-else` is a *statement*. An expression can be used where a statement can be used, but the opposite is not true.

This is a good counterexample to show when you come across somebody who insists that you should never, never, never, ever use conditional expressions, because `if-else` is "simple" and conditionals are "too complicated".

When C++ gets lambda expressions, then you may be able to use a lambda with an `if-else` in place of a conditional.

Comment: +1. It helps to think of the ternary operator as a "replacement".

Comment: -1 Except for the first statement "You are correct" this answer is correct. Depending on what you want to preserve, the conditional operator can or cannot be replaced with other things, but since it depends, it is *wrong* to assert that it cannot. Concrete examples beat assertions every time, so I included concrete examples of rewriting the OP's example with *if* and *switch*.

Comment: The questioner's assertion was "the conditional operator is not always replaceable by an if/else statement."  I think that is correct.  "It depends" and "not always" are almost synonymous.

Comment: no, they're not almost synonyms.  for the choice of preserving the literal source code the statement that cannot be replaced is trivially true but vacuous. choosing different constraints alters the conclusion: given any example where, for a given choice of what to preserve, one finds that `:?` can not be replaced with `if`, a different choice of what to preserve (e.g. as illustrated in my examples) let's you do the replacement. it's like saying you can buy whatever you want for $1, because you decide up front to not want anything costing more. true in that sense, but meaningless.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are obviously lots of places that you can't place an if. For example:

```
func( x ? 0 : 1 );
```

There is no way of writing that with an if statement. And this is a dupe, several times, not that I blame you for not finding it, because I can't.

Comment: +1: mostly true...you could use `if (x) func(0); else func(1);` of course.

Comment: @Roddy Sigh. It depends what you mean by "replace".

Comment: Change it to `const Foo y = func( x ? 0 : 1 )` and @Roddy's complaint disappears.  (Although you could say that `!x` would be better than the conditional, so different values might improve the example.)

Comment: @Roddy, Jonathan: Of course, if there are six other arguments to `func` and you're going to duplicate them in the if-else, it's pretty definitely clearer to use the conditional operator.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly. You can always replace the reference (not re-seatable) with a pointer (re-seatable). So it's a matter of context.

E.g. you can write

```
int* pa;
if( b == 2 )
    pa = &x1;
else
    pa = &x2;
int& a = *pa;
```

No problemo, as someone once remarked to the Terminator.

And going all out for maximum "ugh what's *that*" effect,

```
int* pa;
switch( b == 2 )
{
case true:
    pa = &x1;  break;
default:
    pa = &x2;
}
int& a = *pa;
```

But it's more clear with the conditional operator in this case. :-)

```
int& a = (b == 2? x1 : x2);
```

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: @Nim: well i wondered whether to also include table look-up variant and so on, but decided against, for brief-&-clear effect. :-)

Comment: Correct. Only thing that you forgot break before default:.

Answer (score 2):

You are going to have more problems than that

```
// works
ostream *o;
if(x)
  o = &myfiles;
else
  o = &mystrings;


// stringstream* and fstream* -- incompatible!
ostream *o = x ? &myfiles : &mystrings;
```

Comment: you know, a cast ain't so bad.

Answer (score 1):

You are right.

In C++ there are conditional assignment situations where use of the if-else statement is impossible, since this language explicitly distinguishes between initialization and assignment.

Furthermore, the ternary operator can yield an lvalue, i.e. a value to which another value can be assigned.

Also, some compilers in some cases may generate different code for ternary vs conditional if-then. GCC, for example, performs better code optimization if ternary operator is used.

See also [`?:` ternary operator in C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a#C.2B.2B).

Answer (score 1):

You can't use it directly, but you can always get around that restriction by turning your conditional into something that is evaluated as an expression...

```
int& initValue(int b, int& x1, int& x2){
    if (b==2)
        return x1;
    return x2;
}

...

int& a = initValue(b, x1, x2);
```

Of course, this may be overkill for ints.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your definition of replaceable. For example, within a single function call, I cannot replace the following conditional operator with an `if-else`.

```
int n1 = 10;
int n2 = 20;
const int& i = x > 0 ? n1 : n2;
```

However, with the addition of another function, I've effectively replaced the conditional operator with an `if-else`.

```
const int& get_i(double x)
{
  if(x > 0)
    return n1;
  else
    return n2;
}

int main()
{
  const int& i = get_i(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Acording to [kodify.net](https://kodify.net) we cannot replace every `if/else` statement with the conditional operator. There are two requirements for doing so: there must be one expression in both the **if** and the **else** block.